# Django: View-related functionality, specific for the Model, where to put?

Tags: django, oop, model-view-controller

I.e. I have the Model (actually abstract one, used in many other classes) with two `ImageField` `rendered` and `preview` and it's commonly used operation in views to redirect to `rendered` or `preview` depending on request. So I'd like to put some method in my model, which returns desired `HttpResponseRedirect`, but I feel that it's definitely bad practice to mix Model and View functionality. What is best practice, where to put View-related functionality, specific for the Model?

Comment: Putting the actual HttpResponseRedirect in a model method would be bad, but a method to return the URL to redirect to would be fine; that's what `get_absolute_url` is for example.

Comment: Yes, right, I got you point, so return url and then warp it in HttpResponce in view, it's ok.  But anyway, are there any practices to hold frequently used View operations, related to specific Model?